# express js - GET request 404 not found when using sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize and express.js in server development.

When I try to send GET request for route `/files`, an error shows:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "message": "Not Found",
        "error": {
            "status": 404
        }
    }
}
```

Folder structure

```
src
  -models
    -File.js
  -routes
    -api
      -index.js
      -files.js
  -index.js
  -app.js
  -sequelize.js
package.json
```

I am trying to get ALL records from table `files`

/src/routes/api/files.js

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const Files = require('../../models/File')

router.get('/files', (req,res) => 
    Files.findAll()
    .then(data => {
        res.sendStatus(200)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
);

module.exports = router;
```

/src/routes/index.js

```
var router = require('express').Router();

router.use('/api', require('./api'));

module.exports = router;
```

/src/models/File.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const DataTypes = Sequelize.DataTypes;
const db = require('../sequelize')

let files = db.define('files', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    fileName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
  });
  
module.exports = files;
```

src/sequelize.js

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('myDb', 'admin', '1234', {
  dialect: 'mysql',
  logging: false
});

sequelize.sync({alter: true})

module.exports = sequelize;
```

src/app.js

```
var http = require('http'),
    path = require('path'),
    methods = require('methods'),
    express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    session = require('express-session'),
    cors = require('cors'),
    passport = require('passport'),
    errorhandler = require('errorhandler'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

const sequelize = require('./sequelize')

sequelize.authenticate()
.then(() => {console.log("connected")}) //printed "connected"
.catch((err) => {console.log(err)})


var isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

var app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.use(require('morgan')('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(require('method-override')());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use(session({ secret: 'conduit', cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }, resave: false, saveUninitialized: false  }));

if (!isProduction) {
  app.use(errorhandler());
}

if(isProduction){
  mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
} else {
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/conduit');
  mongoose.set('debug', true);
}

require('./models/File');
app.use(require('./routes'));

/// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

if (!isProduction) {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    console.log(err.stack);

    res.status(err.status || 500);

    res.json({'errors': {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    }});
  });
}

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.json({'errors': {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  }});
});

var server = app.listen( process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){
  console.log('Listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

**Update 1**
src/routes/api/index.js

```
var router = require('express').Router();

router.use('/', require('./users'));
router.use('/files', require('./files'));

router.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  if(err.name === 'ValidationError'){
    return res.status(422).json({
      errors: Object.keys(err.errors).reduce(function(errors, key){
        errors[key] = err.errors[key].message;

        return errors;
      }, {})
    });
  }

  return next(err);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: What is the URL of your request?

Comment: @Đăng Khoa Đinh http://localhost:3000/api/files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

In your `/api/index.js` file you have :

```
router.use('/files', require('./files'));
```

So the URL should be: `http://localhost:3000/api/files/files`

If you want to change the URL to: `http://localhost:3000/api/files`, in your `files.js`, you should change to :

```
router.get('/', (req,res) => // change "/files" to just "/" 
    Files.findAll()
    .then(data => {
        res.sendStatus(200)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
);
```

Comment: sorry it has index.js file in the api folder, I updated above. please have a look

Comment: Can you post the content of this file to your question?

Comment: posted above. please check my update 1. thanks

Comment: If I only want `http://localhost:3000/api/files`, how should I modify it?